# Creating my own custom structure in Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg

In Ollydbg's hex dump window (lower left quadrant of CPU window) one can interpret data as structures, you can right-click on one or more bytes and see the options "Decode as structure" or "Decode as pointer to structure" (if more than one byte selected).  It then opens a new window with the data laid out vertically, with each data element shown as a row.  You can decode more than one instance.

However, I'd like to add my own structure types.  Imagine I have this structure:

```
typedef struct {
           double x,y,z;   
           unsigned char id;
           int label;
           char *name_string;
           anotherStructType *struct;       
           } model_type;
```

Below are some images showing the steps, with the fixed structure type "COORD" chosen.  Imagine I want to decode it instead with the above 'model_type' structure type.  Perhaps the answer lies in some command line or .ini manual setting?

Also, it would be nice if this could be used along with labels to identify struct elements in the disassembly window, for example [EAX+1C] could be interpreted as 'player.id' if one could somehow tell Olly EAX is the base pointer.  But perhaps I'm getting carried away...

[image]

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BE AWARE** `what follows are undocumented stuff`

create a `file either named as [binary].arg` or `common.arg`
the first name is applicable to only to the specific [binary]
the second name common.arg is applicable globally

paste this inside the file

```
STRUCT _MYSTRUCT
QWORD DOUBLE x
QWORD DOUBLE y
QWORD DOUBLE z
BYTE  CHAR  id
DWORD INT label
DWORD ASCII* name
DWORD INT* foo
END
```

drop the file in the folder where ollydbg resides.
_MYSTRUCT should be available in the drop down box now

`STRUCT` is a keyword
struct names need a leading underscore
the members are defined like
FIELDSIZE, TYPENAME , MEMBERNAME

valid FIELDSIZE are

1. BYTE
2. WORD
3. THREE
4. DWORD
5. QWORD
6. TBYTE

that correspond to sizes `1,2,3,4,8,16`
TYEPNAMES are vast you should try and err
i have posted some which are common
Notice i have cast Your last Structure as INT* instead of anotherstruct*
for which you may need to add a custom type in the file
you can specify a repeat count with asterisk *

```
BYTE*48 BYTE somecrap
```

somecrap is MemberName a string

`END is a keyword` denoting end of structure

some dummy src that use the structure from your Query compiled executed and 
screen shot below

src

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct _TESTY {
    int a;
    int b;
}Testy,*PTesty;
typedef struct _MYSTRUCT {
    double x,y,z;
    unsigned char id;
    int label;
    char *name;
    Testy *foo;
}MyStruct,*PMyStruct;

int main (void) {
    MyStruct blah;
    Testy arrgh;
    char *test = "hello do i know c ?";
    memset(&blah,0,sizeof(blah));
    blah.x=43.0;
    blah.y=76.34;
    blah.z=0.0;
    blah.id = 'a';
    blah.label = 54;
    blah.name = test;
    arrgh.a =45;
    arrgh.b =54000;
    blah.foo = &arrgh;
    printf("%f\n",blah.x);
    printf("%s\n",blah.name);
    printf("%d\n",blah.foo->b);
    return 0;   
}
```

executed

```
structy.exe
43.000000
hello do i know c ?
54000
```

running with ollydbg

```
ollydbg.exe structy.exe
```

the log windows shows it used the structure definitions we provided by xxxxx.arg

```
Log data
Address   Message
          OllyDbg v2.01
          Command line: structy.exe
          Loading function descriptions from 'common.arg'
            2 structures
            Total size of known data is 1521777 bytes
```

screen shot 
[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks!  But I can't repeat it in my system, the compiler is optimizing it away and I get a much shorter program with hardcoded values fed to _printf.  I am using Visual Studio 6, compiling for Release with default flags.  I need to find my correct compiler or linker setting to make the full code appear that you have.

Comment: i dont compile debug i always compile release and with highest level of warnings and analyze enabled code shown above is done with windows sdk 7.1 compiler (free )  cl /nologo /Zi /EHsc /O1 /analyze /W4 *.cpp /link /release  so wyswyg should apply

Comment: I fixed the compiler optimization issue, changing it to /Od which is "disable (Debug)".  The default for VS6 Release was /O2 ="optimize speed".  It was simply under the Project Settings->C++ -> Optimizations in the IDE.  I like the idea of doing things from the command line with 'cl' directly, I must try that too.

Comment: This is a great answer, now I can see structures.  It's really useful I believe, at least for looking into my own programs.  I found Blabb's answer worked with Ollydbg 2.01.   I found I could change the .ARG file and simply restart (ctrl-F2) to reload the defn's without having to stop and start Ollydbg like I feared (I thought it might only look at them when I launched Ollydbg).  Sadly in Olldbg when you spawn a structure, list, or other dump window from the main hex dump, it doesn't have the same capabiliites.  I can't spawn another decoded window from the *foo pointer to the 2nd struct type.

Comment: Be aware that numbers are in hexadecimal by default. The `0x` prefix is optional, but required for numbers starting with alpha characters. The `.` suffix can be used for unsigned decimal numbers: `10.`
Also `TBYTE` is 10 bytes in size (which is required for fields using the `LDOUBLE` type). But it was awkward to figure this out before learning everything was in hex. For character arrays, the `ATEXT` type can be used. I've written up more in-depth documentation on the format, there's a lot to it, but it's definitely experimental: https://github.com/trigger-segfault/Ollydbg-Argfile-Docs